# Реалиация связей между таблицами БД (один к одному) с помощью моделей

Tags: laravel

Получаю ошибку:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tlaravel.countries' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `countries` where `countries`.`user_id` = 1 and `countries`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)
```

Таблицы countries нет в БД (была, но из-за неправильного написания названия была удалена). В контроллере к такой таблице не обращаюсь.

Что это - влияние кэша?
Как избавиться?

Спасибо! С уважением Олег.

Comment: php artisan cache:clear  если это кэш ? но вы уверены что у вас в классе User например нет метода country ? который реализует belongsTo(countries) ?

Comment: В классе User:

  public function country() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Country');
  }

Comment: Очистка кэша с помощью команды не помогла!

Comment: Миграция countries была удалена не командой из консоли, вручную из директории database>migrations - может причина в этом ?

Comment: так удалите этот метод, вот он выборку и пытается сделать, тем более у вас где-то этот метод вызывается !

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду метод country ?
Так ведь он определяет связь модели записи из таблицы users c моделью записи из таблицы countrys ?

Comment: Ошибка найдена самостоятельно (модель country была создана, но не сформирована), Ваша подсказка косвенно помогла.
Почему ошибка указывала на ''невидение'' ранее удаленной таблицы - не понятно?!

Comment: Потому что модель была создана, по умолчанию она смотрела в таблицу countries, и только в том случае, если вы ее переопределите она будет смотреть в другое место, вот она и смотрела, куда было по умолчанию!

Comment: Почему Ваш ответ не в формате?
Не могу отблагодарить зеленой галочкой??!!

Comment: Потому что это коммент, а нужно написать ответ :) Я сейчас сформулирую ответ, более точно.

Comment: Еще мне кажется у вас ошибка понимания belongsTo() и hasOne() я бы на вашем месте почитал статью в чем отличие :) например тут https://gist.github.com/greabock/3d1611c1125f5340f491

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Классе User вы описали зависимость от класса Country, класс Country
по умолчанию (если не находит свойства protected $table) использует преобразование к множественному числу класса (countries) и пытается сделать выборку по данной таблице.